# Reduction of the computation time of clustering algorithm

Tags: c++, optimization, cluster-analysis

I wrote a small code that clusters floor areas on a map. It works well however I would like to optimize the computational time. 
Do you have any advice in order to reduce the computation time?

The idea to optimize the algorithm was to use only one vector for the clusters and to go through all the pixels only once.

The algorithm works as follows, it scans all the cells starting in the top left corner and analyzing each row after another. If a cell is detected as a floor, it analyses the neighbors on the left and define if one of them belongs to a cluster. If it's the case, the same cluster number is assigned, if not, a new cluster number is assigned. If two neighbors have different cluster numbers, they are merged together with the "replace" operation.

```
   std::vector<int> PathPlanning::clustering(){
        const int unknown = -1;
        int clusterCount = 0;
        std::vector<int> clusters(m_map.size(), unknown);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < clusters.size(); ++i) {
            if(m_map.at(i) != e_mapState::FLOOR)
                continue;

            for(auto& nb : neighborLeft(i)) {
                if(clusters.at(nb)!= unknown){
                    if(clusters.at(i) == unknown){
                        clusters.at(i) = clusters.at(nb);
                    }else{
                        std::replace (clusters.begin(), clusters.end(), clusters.at(nb), clusters.at(i));
                    }
                }
            }
            if(clusters.at(i) == unknown){
                clusterCount+=1;
                clusters.at(i) = clusterCount;
            }
        }

        return clusters;
    }
```

Comment: It would be great if you could expand your explanation of the algorithm, because the greatest optimization may lay there.
Other than that, if you think your algorithm cannot be improved, you should always run the profiler first and see what it tells you.

Comment: hard to know what´s happening without knowing about m_map and neighborLeft. Also does the replace part ever run?

Comment: The more appropriate term is **connected components**, since your "clusters" do not have statistical properties or models.

Comment: using `.at()` is generally slower then `[]` due to bounds checking. Especially in the outer loop: `clusters` is `m_map.size()` in size, so you don't have to check the bounds for `i`, as `clusters.size()` == `m_map.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a [disjoint set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Disjoint-set_forests) problem, where the running time is O(α(n)), O(1) in practice, per element, so O(n α(n)), O(n) in practice.

Where your code is O(n neighbours n), n and neighbours for the loops, and an additional n for the replace.

There is also some [Boost code](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/disjoint_sets/disjoint_sets.html) available so you might save some time implementing it.